# How does one breed the new Apocalpyse dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I saw the new Apocalypse Dragon in the marketplace.  I heard it has four elements required but I didn't see that in the game, how do I breed it?  Let's hope I get it before the world ends. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the new Apocalpyse Dragon requires four breeding element: Plant, Lightning, Cold and Metal.  So you need two hybrid dragons that contain those elements.

A confirmed combination would be Magnetic Dragon (Metal and Lighting) and Lichen Dragon (Plant and Cold).  It's a limited dragon and only here for a period of time.

Source: [Apocalpyse Dragon on Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/dragon/apocalypse-dragon/tips-hints)

Answer (score 0):

Cactus and Mine/ Copper and Paper/Lichen and magnetic /Mine and Ash